# How to plot a 3d graph in Matlab with my data?

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

Right now I am doing a parameter sweep and I am trying to convert my data to a 3D graph to show the results in a very nice fashion. The problem is that I don't quite know how to plot it as I am having an issue with the result variable.

```
mute_rate = [0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.0625, 0.03125, 0.015625]
mute_step = linspace(-2.5, 2.5, 6)
results = [949.58, 293.53,  57.69, 53.65, 293.41, 1257.49; 
        279.19, 97.94, 32.60, 29.52, 90.52, 286.94;
        32.96, 28.06, 19.56, 6.44, 13.47, 55.80;
        2.01, 1.52, 5.38, 1.00, 0.89, 1.41;
        0.61, 0.01, 18.59, 0.03, 0.56, 1.22;
        1.85, 1.51, 18.64, 18.57, 18.54, 6.90]
```

So the first row in the result variable presents the results of the mute rate and mute step performed on the population from my genetic algorithm. For example:

> 0.5, -2.5 = 949.58,

> 0.5, -1.5 = 293.53,

> 0.5, -0.5 = 57.69

etc

Comment: What is your issue with the results variable? What is the code you have tried? What type of 3D plot would you like?

Comment: @RobertoT I would like to have a graph that converges to 0 and show how the mute rate and mute step affect the results. The issue with the result variable is that I am not sure how to use it as it is a 6x6 matrix and the rest of the vectors are one-dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something akin to:

```matlab
mesh(mute_step, mute_rate, results);
shading interp;
```

Other styles of plot would be `surf` or `pcolor` (for a 2d view).